# How to mud painted wall to accommodate new lower baseboards

Tags: baseboard, mudding

First time posting here.
I'm working on an old house, discarded old baseboards and repainted a few walls.
When about to put on new baseboards, I'm finding that my old baseboards were higher than the new ones, and so I'm having this ugly transition from were the edge was on the old base boards visible, see picture.

So, I will need to re-mud and repaint by the baseboard area. Any good tips on how to approach this? What mud is best to use on paint? All purpose? Hot Mud?
Any other tips welcome on how to go about to fix this rookie mistake??

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a lite topping mud or all purpose, not hot mud as it is hard to sand.

I would use a 5" or 6" knife and go around the perimeter and fix areas as needed.

If you have access to a hand masker I would recommend running around and masking the floor with some 9 or 12" paper, especially if you have limited experience doing mud work. It will save you some time doing clean up.

Once you've completed your mud work you'll need to sand, vacuum, prime and paint.

If you have already painted the walls in the areas where you will be doing mud work, those repaired areas will need two coats of paint and will need to be feathered into the body.

Answer (score 0):

Hot mud will dry faster of course, but all purpose works as well.  It depends on how long you want to wait for the mud to dry.

I have sanded over the rough edges around the repair area before applying the mud. Then applied a liberal coat of mud.  When dry I sanded lightly then wiped it with a damp sponge to make it even smoother.

Prime and paint and you are done.